# How to check for negative values in a list recursively?

Tags: python, list

I need to check if there are any negative numbers in a list and if there are I have to return False.

```
def check_negative(vals):
    if vals[0] < 0:
        return False
    else:
        ...
        return True
```

So if my list is --> [1, 0, -7, 8, 21] it should return False and it should only return True if all numbers are positive.

edit:
After receiving feedback I realized doing it recursively isn't efficient so I have edited my code.

```
def no_negatives(numbers):
    positive = []
    negative = []
    for num in numbers:
        if num >= 0:
            positive.append(num)
        else:
            negative.append(num)
    if len(negative) > 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

I got my expected output. Thanks everyone.

Comment: You have no recursion here? you can either do it recursivly or loop over the list and check each element, which way do you want?

Comment: Why would you want to do this using recursion? Try to avoid recursion wherever possible.

Comment: I would like to do it recursively

Comment: @Rozy If this is just an exercise, fine. But in Python, recursion is both far slower than a loop and limits you due to the fixed upper limit on the size of the call stack.

Comment: But basically, all you need to do is call `check_negative` on the *rest* of the list (`vals[1:]`) if `vals[0]` is non-negative.

Comment: Where you have " . . . " simply call the function again with the first element of the list popped

Comment: Exactly what @chepner wrote.

Comment: (Note that `vals[1:]` itself is *copy* of (most of) the list, another reason not to use recursion. You can mitigate that by passing the list and starting index as arguments, so that you can pass the same list to each recursive call, avoiding the copy.)

Comment: Okay, you want to do it recursively, There are already great answers but if you want to do it in a simpler form, I would recommend utilizing the any function. You can reduce your function to two lines of Code:
def check_negative(vals): <br>
  return not any(e < 0 for e in vals)

Answer (score 1):

#### Recursive

As others have pointed out you should not use recursion for this kind of thing in a production application as it consumes much more resources for the call stack (which is also limited in Python), but if you want to use it for training purposes you can do it like this.

You need two simple base cases here:

- List is empty: return `True` as there cannot be negative values in an empty list
- List has at least one value and the value is smaller than 0: return `False` as then we have found a value which is negative in the array

In all other cases we just call the function recursively and return the result.

```py
lst1 = [1, 0, -7, 8, 21]
lst2 = [1, 0, 234, 2342, 23423, 32, 324, 8, 21]


def check_has_negative_rec(arr):
    """
    Checks recursively whether a list contains a negative element or not.
    :param arr: list to check
    :return: True, if list contains negative element, False otherwise
    """
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return False
    elif arr[0] < 0:
        return True
    else:
        return check_has_negative_rec(arr[1:])


print(check_has_negative_rec(lst1))
print(check_has_negative_rec(lst2))
```

Expected output:

```
True
False
```

#### Iterative

Here how you would do it the iterative way.

```py
lst1 = [1, 0, -7, 8, 21]
lst2 = [1, 0, 234, 2342, 23423, 32, 324, 8, 21]

def check_has_negative_iter(arr):
    for no in arr:
        if no < 0:
            return True
    return False

print(check_has_negative_iter(lst1))
print(check_has_negative_iter(lst2))
```

#### Built-in

You can also use Python built-in [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) which would make your code more pythonic.

```py
lst1 = [1, 0, -7, 8, 21]
lst2 = [1, 0, 234, 2342, 23423, 32, 324, 8, 21]

def check_has_negative_builtin(arr):
    return any(no < 0 for no in arr)

print(check_has_negative_builtin(lst1))
print(check_has_negative_builtin(lst2))
```

All three will give you the same result.

Comment: This is the most comprehensive answer and as such should be marked as the solution.

Comment: There's little reason to use `map` here instead of a generator expression, which will avoid the overhead of the wrapper `lambda`: `any(no < 0 for no in arr)`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks. adjusted my answer to use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

0. Return `True` if the list is empty
1. Check if the first element is negative, return `False` if so
2. Otherwise, apply the same process to the rest of the elements

Implementation:

```
def all_positive(lst):
    if not lst:
        return True
    if lst[0] < 0:
        return False
    rest = lst[1:]
    return all_positive(rest)
```

This is not performant, I'm assuming you want to use recursion for educational reasons.

You can get around creating list slices by using iterators (this won't make the recursion fast, though).

```
def all_positive(lst):
    lst = iter(lst) # NOOP if lst already iterator
    
    try:
        if next(lst) < 0:
            return False
    except StopIteration:
        return True

    return all_positive(lst)
```

Comment: In your first code snippet why do you declare `rest` ? When you can just pass `lst[1:]` as a parameter? Doesnt that declaration allocate memory?

Comment: @JosipJuros for educational reasons, because I used the word "rest" under point 2. Why do you think additional memory would be allocated when assigning a name to `lst[1:]`?

Comment: I was referencing C/c++/c# and there every declaration allocated memory, so I was thought to avoid declaring too many variables.

Comment: @JosipJuros assignment via the `=` operator never copies data in Python.

Comment: Good to know, thank you very much for clearing that up for me :)

Answer (score -1):

The is no recursion involved, you just need list processing.

```
def check(my_list):
    for x in my_list:
      if x < 0:
        return False:

    return True
```

Also you should share you attempt, not simply ask for a solution. It's about learning not having someone else do your homework.

Comment: But what if OP prefers recursive?

Comment: Honestly since the items in the list are not other lists the only way to use recursion would be to make the loop a recursive function but I honestly don't see the point. It's bad practice and a poor way to learn what recursion is and how its used.